# apache SetEnvIf access query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do you access the query string from SetEnvIf? Somethig like:

```
SetEnvIf Query_String "p=path/to/file$" got_path
```

**UPDATE**:

In htaccess, I have:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI !/folder/page1\.html$ NO_COOKIE
Header unset Cookie env=NO_COOKIE
RewriteRule (.*) /h.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Basically, I ask `h.php` to take control of all user requests. And I use `SetEnvIf` to allow cookies  **only** for `/folder/page1.html`.

However, it seems like `Request_URI` is always set to "h.php" and never to " /folder/page1.html" (maybe because of the redirection). For that reason I added `ref=$1` to try to recognize which url it is being redirected from. Therefore I need to read the query string from `SetEnvIf`.

I hope I am making some sense.

Comment: how would you work around it?

Comment: I am trying to read the Request_URI before a rewrite. I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a query string for this.

You can use:

```
# always start with NO_COOKIE=1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_COOKIE:1]

# unset NO_COOKIE when URI is /folder/page1.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/page1\.html
RewriteRule ^ - [E=!NO_COOKIE]

Header set NoCookie %{NO_COOKIE}e
RequestHeader set NoCookie %{NO_COOKIE}e
```

Comment: I just had to make a small change: `[E=NO_COOKIE:]` by `[E=!NO_COOKIE]`